# which multi thread model would be better to program a server to respond to udp or tcp?

Tags: multithreading

If we need to design and implement a server to respond to udp or tcp requests, which multi-thread model should we use?

i researched online but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: Welcome to **Stack Overflow**! Please visit the [**Help Center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) because it has useful information that will guide you in the right direction and  provides detailed instructions explaining: [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); [how to present your problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); [what questions belong here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what questions don't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server architectures have interchanged heavyweight processes with new lightweight threads. Thread-per-connection model is used more. Along with sharing same address space, it also share global state and variable. Hence for individual request handlers, mutual structures can be executed, like for cacheable reactions inside the web server a mutual cache is developed. It is mandatory to have precise organization and management.